# Java: Returning XMLType Data from StoredProcedure, Usage of ojdbc6.jar xdb6.jar xmlparserv2.jar for Java to PLSQL interaction

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, xmltype

I am following  the below tutorial to retrieve XMLType data from a stored procedure

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14259/xdb11jav.htm#g1039140
*Example 13-4 XMLType Java: Returning XMLType Data*

When I run the code, I get this **error**,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/xml/parser/v2/XMLParseException
    at oracle.xdb.XMLTypeFactory.create(XMLTypeFactory.java:67)
    at oracle.sql.OPAQUE.toClass(OPAQUE.java:328)
    at oracle.sql.OPAQUE.toJdbc(OPAQUE.java:278)
    at oracle.sql.OPAQUE.toJdbc(OPAQUE.java:259)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.NamedTypeAccessor.getObject(NamedTypeAccessor.java:190)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.NamedTypeAccessor.getObject(NamedTypeAccessor.java:117)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.getObject(OracleCallableStatement.java:1579)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatementWrapper.getObject(OracleCallableStatementWrapper.java:815)
    at com.example.TestXMLDAO.main(TestXMLDAO.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParseException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 9 more
```

**Java code snippet:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes;
import oracle.xdb.XMLType;
```

.............

```
            // Prepare to call the stored procedure get_group_details.

            String sql = "{call mypackage.get_records(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}";

            callableStatement = conn.prepareCall(sql);

            callableStatement.setString(1, "");
            callableStatement.setString(2, "");
            callableStatement.setString(3, "");
            callableStatement.setString(4, "");
            callableStatement.setString(5, "abb%");
            callableStatement.setString(6, "F");
            callableStatement.setString(7, "F");
            callableStatement.registerOutParameter(8, OracleTypes.OPAQUE,
                    "SYS.XMLTYPE");

            // execute get_group_details
            // callableStatement.executeQuery();

            callableStatement.executeQuery();

            callableStatement.getObject(8);

            // get cursor and cast it to ResultSet
            xml = (XMLType) callableStatement.getObject(8);

            System.out.println(xml.getStringVal());

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // Close the statement
            callableStatement.close();
            // Close the connection
            conn.close();
        }
```

**PLSQL Procedure snippet**

```
PROCEDURE get_records
   (
      grp1     IN a.name%TYPE DEFAULT NULL
     ,grp2 IN a.name%TYPE DEFAULT NULL
     ,grp3        IN a.name%TYPE DEFAULT NULL
     ,grp4          IN a.name%TYPE DEFAULT NULL
     ,grp5               IN a.name%TYPE DEFAULT NULL
     ,flag1     IN a.flag%TYPE DEFAULT 'F'
     ,flag2       IN a.flag%TYPE DEFAULT 'F'
     ,xml_type_out        OUT xmltype
   );
```

Jars included: ojdbc6.jar, xdb.jar

Any idea what I am missing?

This issue is resolved. But when deployed in JBoss server, another issue - please refer here if you have any ideas - [Xmlparserv2 error while application deployed in jboss, Installing Oracle ojdbc module in JBoss for Java web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26370270/xmlparserv2-error-while-application-deployed-in-jboss)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Issue fixed by adding the required jars

Needed the following three jars in the classpath, [I had these jars still, I was getting error due to wrong versions of the jar]

**ojdbc6.jar, xdb6.jar, xmlparserv2-11.1.1.jar**

Even if you have these jars, you might get error like I was getting when I was including a wrong version of xmlparserv2.jar.

So Important thing to take care is the version and compatibility of these jars.

The ones that worked for me [My Oracle DB version : 11.2.0.4.0]

**ojdbc6.jar; xdb6.jar:**

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html

**xmlparserv2-11.1.1.jar**
 available here: ( [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html) ) (in sqldeveloper\modules\oracle.xdk_12.1.2)

[removed third party reference link as advised by @Lukas Eder, Thanks for that]

Comment: *"xmlparserv2-11.1.1.jar ..."* - Really? Some random, inofficial 3rd party maven repository? This could contain arbitrary malicious code, plus I doubt it's legal from a licensing perspective!

Comment: I tried once with a xmlparserv2.jar obtained from SQL Developer, but that didn't help me. may be due to version. However as you said, yes need to follow what you said. Lemme try with the link you shared in answer

Comment: Marking this as answer as this is the complete one.

Answer (score 6):

There's a distribution of `xmlparserv2.jar` in various Oracle products, among which [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html) (in sqldeveloper\modules\oracle.xdk_12.1.2).

Of course, I have no clue if you're allowed to extract that jar from SQL Developer, license wise.

Comment: Appreciate posting as answer with the link, +1. I will mark this as answer as soon as I try and I also agree that this is the way

Comment: @spiderman: Feel free to embed the link in your own answer, though. I found it quite complete, otherwise...

Answer (score 1):

Class

```
oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParseException
```

is in xmlparserv2.jar

Available at http://www.oracle.com/us/downloads/index.html

Comment: ok, Added the jar +1. now getting `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/jdbc/oci8/OCIDBAccess` . let me try maven to find dependencies

Comment: That wasn't a good idea:( as these jars are not available in public repo, we have to download jars, install in local repo and then refer in pom.xml, Hence doesnt help

Comment: another exception when application is deployed at JBoss server - I created a SO thread for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26370270/xmlparserv2-error-while-application-deployed-in-jboss