# logstash SQL Query not able to read (XMLTYPE) field

Tags: elasticsearch, oracle11g, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am trying to read a column containing (XMLTYPE) data from my Oracle DB through logstash config file. But it looks like some xml parsing error is occuring.

**Query**

select ilmd from event;

**Logstash Config File**

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_validate_connection => true
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orcl"
        jdbc_user => "abc"
        jdbc_password => "abc"
        jdbc_driver_library => "/home/user/ES/ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.0.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        statement => "SELECT ilmd FROM event"
       }
}
filter {
}
output   {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

**Exception On Console**

```
Exception when executing JDBC query {:exception=>#<Sequel::DatabaseError: Java::JavaLang::NoClassDefFoundError: oracle.xdb.XMLTypeFactory>, :level=>:warn}
```

Can somebody help me on this, please.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs due to a typo error in your `jdbc_driver_class`. It should look something like this:

```
jdbc {
        jdbc_validate_connection => true
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orcl"
        jdbc_user => "abc"
        jdbc_password => "abc"
        jdbc_driver_library => "/home/user/ES/ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.0.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        statement => "SELECT ilmd FROM event"
     }
```

Comment: Although it was working file for other query from same database, I tried your suggestion and got an exception,                Error: java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver not loaded. Are you sure you've included the correct jdbc driver in :jdbc_driver_library?
You may be interested in the '--configtest' flag which you can
use to validate logstash's configuration before you choose
to restart a running system.

Comment: My connection settings are okay, what is not working is XML parsing thing, please look in to it.

Comment: If I try to fetch some non-xml filed from the Db it is working fine with that, the problem is with (XMLTYPE) filed in the DB.

Comment: It seems like you need the [xdb.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/x/Downloadxdbjar.htm) as well which contains XMLTypeFactory class. This [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25208239/java-returning-xmltype-data-from-storedprocedure-usage-of-ojdbc6-jar-xdb6-jar) kinda proves it.